# is there a way to automate/script (eg perl) a tagged pdf file to see if it's pdf/ua compliant?

Tags: pdf, accessibility

We have some tools that generate PDF.  We want to automate some testing to make sure the generated PDFs are tagged (PDF/UA) and that the tags are valid.

There are a lot of interactive checkers (acrobat, [PDF Accessibility Checker](http://www.access-for-all.ch/en/pdf-lab/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac.html) (PAC), etc).  They generate reports of things that pass/fail in the PDF based on the [matterhorn protocol](http://www.pdfa.org/publication/the-matterhorn-protocol-1/).  I'd like to generate these similar reports but automated.

I recently found a perl module, [PDF::API2](http://search.cpan.org/~ssimms/PDF-API2-2.025/lib/PDF/API2.pm), that might be promising but I only wrote a few simple tests with perl about 15 years ago.  Has anyone used that module for tagged pdf checking or have you done this with a different scripting language?

Comment: Looking at the Matterhorn protocol, it shows that there are quite a few tests which need human interaction/decision. For these, you can help getting to the items, but not much more. OTOH, for the machine-testable items, there should by now be preflight profiles/checks for Acrobat. That would allow to put together a preflight profile, which can be turned into a droplet, which would create reports, and allow to separate files passing and failing. You might also contact Callas Software.

Answer (score 0):

The technology used in Adobe Acrobat (in its Preflight component) is developed by callas software (caution: I'm heavily affiliated with this company). callas also develops the same technology under the name pdfaPilot, which exists in a manual version but also in command-line and SDK versions that fully automate the process.

But!

As stated by Max Wyss in his comment on your question already, there are two parts to PDF/UA checking. Some of the specification's rules can be tested automatically by software, but a lot of them cannot.

To give one example, it is possible to verify programmatically that all text in a PDF document is tagged with a language. It's a whole other ballgame to check whether those language tags are actually correct.

pdfaPilot Desktop actually allows you to automatically check what is possible, and then allows you to convert the PDF/UA file into visually tagged HTML which makes it much easier to verify that meaning and structure of the text are correct.

In other words, yes, such technology exists, but it will never be 100% complete.

Comment: There is more to tagging and validation than the language. For example, an image that is tagged as an image also needs to have an alternative text. A computer can determine whether that exists but only a human can determine whether the text accurately describes the image. This has nothing to do with language. The tool you listed does not do everything, or even close to everything that is related to accessibility. Your answer is invalid.

Comment: Sir, first of all, I didn't downvote your answer. I will do now, just to make a point. Secondly, when talking about what the limits are, I wrote this "To give one example". So yes, I know there is more than language. Also, perhaps if you read my answer correctly, you will also read this "Some ... can be tested automatically ..., but a lot of them cannot". I cannot be more clear than this I'm afraid. If you're pissed off about someone posting about a competitive product, take it up with that person directly instead of leaving incorrect and frankly stupid comments.

Comment: I don't care whether you downvoted my answer or not, your answer is invalid because it does not address the central tenet of the question - accessibility.

Comment: @unobf As an impartial third party, I must say that David's answer is indeed incomplete (and he admits this in his answer; giving a complete answer to this question would require to write a full spec), but David's answer is correct. It is also a much better answer than yours. An answer like yours is usually not accepted by the community. Read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) where it says *Provide context for links.* I have cast a vote to delete your answer for that reason.